# Allow outside touch for PopupWindows

Tags: android

Allow outside touch for PopupWindows
i have an image view and when i touch it an popup window appear on touched x and y point
my problem here is that i want to touch outside the popup window and run imageview on touch event in the same time and dismiss the popup window
now i click outside the popup window to dismiss then another click to run imageview on touch event

here is a solution to this problem but in dialogfragment is any similar way in popupwindows

```
// Make the dialog possible to be outside touch   
 dialogWindow.setFlagsWindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

dialogWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to cancel or dismiss your popup window then use this property

```
dialogWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Comment: it`s popup window class

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code:

```
dialogWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Comment: it`s popup window class